# How to send multiple objects to web method through ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

i want to send 2 objects in ajax, among the two objects one object contains list of records

Can any one help how to do that, i am using following block of code but not working

```
var obj = {};
obj.ChangeDetails = "";
obj.ChangeInformation = "";
obj.ChangeVersion = "";
obj.CSProduct = "";  
obj.Description = $("#caseDesc").val();
obj.EndDate = $("#newSchEdDt").val();
obj.EndDateSpecified = $("#newSchEdTime").val();
obj.Environment = $('#caseEnv').find(":selected").text();  
obj.Operation = "";
obj.RiskAssessment = $("input[name=ccRisk]").val();
obj.SiteEnvironment = "";
obj.SOPDetails = $("#ccSOP").val();
obj.SOPReferenced = "";
obj.SOPVersion = $("#ccSOPVer").val();
obj.StartDate = $("#newSchStDt").val();
obj.StartDateSpecified = $("#newSchStTime").val();
obj.Subject = $("#caseSubj").val();

var Members= {};
Members.cstdetails = newCustList;

var postData = {
    objEmp: obj,
    objMem: Members
};   

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "c9newcaseModel.aspx/CreateCase",     
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,   
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),

    success: function (result) {         
        alert(result.d)           
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
    }
});

public static string CreateCase(CreateCase objEmp, srcCustlst[] objMem)
{ 

}
```

I have created CreateCase and srcCustlst classes with corresponding properties.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You cant POST two separate objects to a POST API.

Rather what you can do is enclose an the two classes within another wrapper class and then pass it as input to your method and form JSON from your client side appropriately.

Different data can be sent to a POST method via URL or via body. But in your situation since both are complex objects better way is to use a wrapper class which contains the two classes that you have and pass data appropriately from client side.

wrapper class can be as below:

```
public class RequestWrapper
{
    public CreateCase objEmp { get; set; }
    public srcCustlst[] objMem { get; set; }

}
```

and may be in your post method change your data to `data: postData,`